# How to download pdf to mobile device flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I have this method that gets pdf from api and returns decoded file, I am able to display it on click, but i want to save it to device.
Here is my method for decoding pdf:

```
  Future<File> _storeFile(String bytes) async {
    final filename = "${_dokument?.naziv}";
    final bytes = _dokument?.bytes;
    Uint8List base64Decode(String source) => base64.decode(source);

    await checkDocumentFolder();

    String dir = directory!.path;

    //final file = File('${dir.path}/$filename');
    final file = File('$dir/$filename');
    //var pdfBytes = bytes?.split(",")[1];
    if (!file.existsSync()) file.create();
    var pdfBytes = bytes?.substring(bytes.indexOf(",") + 1);
    print(pdfBytes);
    await file.writeAsBytes(base64Decode(pdfBytes!), flush: true);

    return file;
  }
```

So my question is, can i somehow save file returned from this method to mobile device.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61506700/11404883

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few things to consider.

Saving a file differs on various devices. In the case of PDF files, I assume that you want them to be easily accessible to the user. To make it happen, it can't be stored in the application's files - it would require a lot of digging to find the file by the user himself.

It also requires several permissions, some of which are configured directly in platform-specific files and some have to be requested from the user in runtime. [Permission Handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package comes in handy for this job.

So, here is how to implement it:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

`iOS`

```
Future<void> saveFile(String fileName) async {
  var file = File('');

  // Platform.isIOS comes from dart:io
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    file = File('${dir.path}/$fileName');
  }
```

To make it work on iOS you have to add 2 keys to `ios/Runner/Info.plist` file.

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

`Android`

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  var status = await Permission.storage.status;
  if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      status = await Permission.storage.request();
  }
  if (status.isGranted) {
      const downloadsFolderPath = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/';
      Directory dir = Directory(downloadsFolderPath);
      file = File('${dir.path}/$fileName');
  }
}
```

For Android, on the other hand, you'll have to do a few more things.

At first, it is required to set proper `compileSdkVersion` in `android/app/build.gradle` file. As I'm writing this - it should be set to `33`.

Also 2 lines are needed in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, right below `manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And of course, as it can be seen in the code - we also need to request a permission from a user.

`Writing to the file`

```
  // load file that you want to save on user's phone
  // it can be loaded from whenever you want, e.g. some API.
  final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$fileName');
  try {
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
        .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
  } on FileSystemException catch (err) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

[File Saver](https://pub.dev/packages/file_saver) package saves files to the application's data, so it won't be so easy to find for the user. It is also published by an unverified uploader so I'd definitely keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can store your file in device
i suggest you to see [this article](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) and [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_file_manager/latest/)

also you can use [file_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/file_saver) package to store file all platform flutter support

Comment: It is worth to keep in mind that file saver package saves files to the application's data, so it won't be so easy to find for the user. It is also published by an unverified uploader which may not be the best for the production code.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
downloadFile(var filePath, var documentUrl) async {
try {
  /// setting filename 
  final filename = filePath;
  String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  if (await File('$dir/$filename').exists()) return File('$dir/$filename');

  String url = documentUrl;

  /// requesting http to get url
  var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url));

  /// closing request and getting response
  var response = await request.close();

  /// getting response data in bytes
  var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);

  /// generating a local system file with name as 'filename' and path as '$dir/$filename'
  File file = new File('$dir/$filename');

  /// writing bytes data of response in the file.
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

  return file;
}
catch (err) {
  print(err);
}
```

}

Comment: This all seems similar to my code, I also use writeAsBytes method but it does not seem to download file to devices localstorage

Comment: @Ranko Did u find final solution for this? i'm facing similar issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to create file locally first then write data into this file :
here's the entire function:

```
downloadFileLocally(Response<dynamic> response) async {

Directory? directory = Platform.isAndroid
           ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
           : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final fullPath =
    '${directory?.path}/NewDirectory';//create new directory here

Directory(fullPath).createSync(recursive: true);

List<int> intList = [];

if(response.data != null) {
  intList = response.data.cast<int>().toList();
}

Uint8List? bytes = Uint8List.fromList(intList);

File? file;
final path = '${iosDirectory?.path}/NewDirectory/$fileType-${fileNameHere}.pdf';
  file = File(path);

try {
  await file.writeAsBytes(
      bytes.buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes));
} on FileSystemException catch (err) {
  // handle error
}


 }
```